# Is RapidSSL WildCard Cert suitable for my eCommerce Web site?

Tags: security-certificate

We have recently launched our online T-Shirts shop which is based on eCommerce platform but certainly we have been facing problem of customer’s transactions security as they were asking for suitable security of their confidential information while shop online over the my website.

One of my friends is being used RapidSSL WildCard Certificate from RapidSSLonline.com

To be clear that we don’t know much about SSL certificate security but we have found that SSL certificates ensure the online web site visitors towards their digital transaction safety. We would like to know that

Is RapidSSL Wildcard Certificate the right choice for eCommerce shop?

Answer (score 4):

Any wildcard certs are bad choice, if you don't want to have a network of sites under common domain-name.

For **one site** you haven't reasons for wildcarded cert (this cert is also greatly more expensive)

Answer (score 0):

As Lazy Badger alluded to, wildcard certificates are designed for setups where you need a single certificate for a (large) number of subdomains.

Wildcard certificates can typically be 5~10x or more the cost of a regular SSL certificate. And for a standard e-commerce site, there should be no reason to need more than a single FQDN.

Even if you have 2-4 subdomains you want a signed certificate for (e.g. `svn.example.com`, `www.example.com` and `static.example.com`), it's still cheaper to buy separate non-wildcard certificates.

Now, if you need signed certificates for a larger range of subdomains or are using wildcard DNS records so every user on your site can have their own subdomain, then a wildcard certificate might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with above two answers as there is no point to go for wildcard certificate until and unless you are plan to have multiple sub-domains on you eCommerce website.

I just did research about SSL certificates that best suited your requirement and compared prices on authority sites first like: thawte, rapidssl, geotrust, symantec. I also did research on various resellers selling same product as lower rate and found that AlphaSSL certificates available at many certificate authority websites at lower rate and will fulfill your requirements.

Kindly review this product and ask your webmaster to confirm the same.

Hope it will work !!